# Calling a function based on argument of previous function in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to do exercise 36 (spend a week making a text-based game) in "Learn Python The Hard Way".

Want I want to do is run `func_1(x)` and then have that run `func_x(0)`. I can't figure out how to do that though. I've tried just writing `func_x(0)` but it returns a `NameError: Global name 'func_' is not defined`. I also tried `func + x + (0)` and I get the same `NameError`. I thought maybe if I could peice the function's name together prior to calling it that would work so I did `func = 'func_' + str(x) + '(0)'` and then tried `room` but that just didn't do anything at all. When I `print` it does return as `func_x(0)`.

This is my code that I am trying to get the above to work in. `n, x, o, y` were included for completeness. I removed the rest of the code to make this more concise and tested the below before posting to make sure everything else was still running fine.

```
import sys
from time import sleep

def in_room(r, n, x, o, y):

    in_room = True
    search_times = 0
    while in_room == True:
        action = raw_input("What would you like to do?:> ")

        if action == 'search' and search_times < 1:
            print (n, x, o, y)
            search_times += 1
        elif action == 'search' and 1 <= search_times:
            print "There is nothing in the room."
        elif action == 'go through right door':
            in_room = False
        elif action == 'go through left door':
            in_room = False
        elif action == 'look around':
            room_r(0)

def room_1(state):
    words ="""
    You are in a dank room. 
    The walls are wet and the floor slimey.
    There is a door to your left and right.
    The door behind you closes.
    """
    for char in words:
        sleep(0.02)
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
    if state == 0:
        return


    in_room(1, 1, 6, 1, 6)

room_1(1)
```

Comment: You could probably use `eval`: `eval('func_' + str(x) + '(0)')`. That's kind of an anti-pattern, though.

Comment: "You are in a dank room"? I thought only memes were dank.

Comment: Everything is object in Python, you can use easily inspect the list of functions available and from their build your code on the fly. But I guess this is not the right path to take, try and reason out a much simpler way. Or are you thinking of missing method (used in Ruby). That way you can call function that is not yet in existence and work out something from it.

Comment: "How Can Our Memes Be Dank If Our Rooms Aren't Dank?" - Jaden Smith

Comment: @grantmcconnaughey that worked! I have no idea what "anti-pattern" is though.

Comment: Hey @IanPringle, I'm glad to hear it. By "anti-pattern" I mean using eval is frowned upon in the Python community. My actual answer would be a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a `list` to get the function you want to invoke:

```
funcs = [
    func_0,
    func_1,
    func_2,
]

# Get the correct function
# x would need to be a number 0-2 in this case
func = funcs[x]

# Call the function
func(0)
```

Comment: Why a dictionary if you have numerical indices anyways? this could as well be a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can look through globals() and locals() for function name, like this:

```
elif action == 'look around':
  fname = "room_%d" % r
  possibles = globals().copy()
  possibles.update(locals())
  func = possibles.get(fname)
  if not func:
       raise NotImplementedError("Function %s not implemented" % fname)
  func(0)
```